# Moving large files with modern authentication

Tags: sharepoint-online, csom

I am trying move files from one site collection to another. Following code works for smaller files but not for large files due to memory exceptions:

```
if (item.FileSystemObjectType == FileSystemObjectType.File)
{
    var fileName = item["FileLeafRef"] as string;
    var fileSize = item["File_x0020_Size"];


    item.Context.Load(item.File);

    using (var stream = item.File.OpenBinaryStream().Value)
    { 
        item.Context.ExecuteQueryWithIncrementalRetry(3, logger);

        var fi = new FileCreationInformation();
        fi.ContentStream = stream;
        fi.Url = fileName;
        fi.Overwrite = true;
        folder.Files.Add(fi);
        destLibrary.Context.ExecuteQueryWithIncrementalRetry(3, logger);
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to to the same in batches? Notice SaveBinary etc cannot be used with modern authentication.

Comment: Did you try recommendations in https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/upload-large-files-sample-app-for-sharepoint?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I read that article, but it is based on uploading a file from disk. I havent found a sample where you can do OpenBinaryStream in batches. Options 3 would be the prefered one but from memory only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one solves the problem:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/mt796381(v%3Doffice.15)